# Ruby on Rails associations for has_many, through, source returns NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models `user.rb`, `vote.rb`, and `event.rb`

User

```
 has_many :votes, foreign_key: 'voter_id', dependent: :destroy
 has_many :voting, through: :votes, source: :voted
```

Vote

```
  belongs_to :voter, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :voted, class_name: "Event"
```

Event

```
  has_many :votes, foreign_key: 'voted_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :voters, through: :votes, source: :voter
```

For some reason, if I call `User.first.voting` I get: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'voted' for #<User:0x00007fbc56d069d8>`

Anybody know why? I have googled a few other questions regarding this topic and I don't see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Ah. In this link, https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-followers, the author is able to do `User has_many :following`, why can I not do the same?

Comment: Try flipping the `source` around? It's telling you that there is no method called `voted`...

Comment: I don't see an issue with the association setup.  Where are getting the error?  Are you calling `User.first.voting` in the console?

Comment: can u provide the schema of these models?

Comment: and rails version

Answer (score 0):

If you're on rails 5, I made a working code:

User

```
  has_many :votes, foreign_key: 'voter_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :voting, through: :votes, source: :voted
```

Event

```
  has_many :votes, foreign_key: 'voted_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :voters, through: :votes, source: :voter
```

Vote

```
  belongs_to :voter, class_name: "User", optional: true
  belongs_to :voted, class_name: "Event", optional: true
```

Schema

```
  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "voter_id"
    t.integer "voted_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

To test (rails console)

```
> User.create
> Event.create
> Vote.create(:voter_id => 1, :voted_id => 1)
> User.first.voting
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
> User.first.voting.first # to get event instance
=> #<Event ...
```

Hope this helps!